# Play Framework Java - package play.db does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.4

I'm using Java as programming language and Play (2.4) as my framework

```
    1 package controllers;
    2
    3 import java.sql.Connection;
    4 import play.db.*;
    5
    6 public class JDBCUtilities {
    7   
    8   
    9   Connection connection = DB.getConnection();
```

Line number 4 was highlighted as an error. In my eclipse IDE, it doesn't seem to show error.

Comment: So if your IDE does not show an error, who shows it? Do you see the error during sbt compile?

Comment: Did you try `activator eclipse`?

Comment: Assuming it's because of `Play! DB Module`, try adding below dependency in your `pom.xml`: `<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.playframework.modules.db</groupId>
 <artifactId>play-db</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
`

Comment: @Anton it's the browser that shows the error. Here's the image. http://imgur.com/nMJBuqg

Comment: @Arpit I can't find the location of pom.xml

Comment: @Zelgh well this package exists in Play 2.4 for sure (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/db/package-frame.html). What Arpit suggested is for Maven. You need the SBT dependencies - in the `build.sbt` file. But it seems that this dependency is really outdated (if I am not mistaken, it was for Play 1.x)

Comment: @Zelgh try doing `activator clean compile run`

Comment: @Anton I did what you said. This happened: http://imgur.com/t1mLkbs

Answer (score 1):

In Play 2.4.x you should ask it to inject the database for you. For example:

```
import play.db.Database;
import javax.inject.*;

public class MyController extends Controller {

    @Inject Database db;

    public Result index() {
        Connection conn = db.getConnection();
        // do something
        return ok("Hi");
    }

}
```

Also make sure you have in your build.sbt the jdbc dependency (note that this does not include JDBC drivers...):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // ...
  javaJdbc,
  // ...
)
```

More info: [Accessing an SQL database - Play 2.4.x doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDatabase)